# Solving recurrence relation $a_n=3a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+2^n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I need to solve the following recurrence relation:

$a_n=3a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+2^n$

For the homonogenous part, it's quite simple and I get:

$a_n^h=\lambda_1+\lambda_22^n$

The nonhomonogenous part is where I get lost. Since one of the solutions from the equation (that I got from Euler's substutution) turns out to be $2$, I need to use the following substitution for $a_n$ :

$a_n=A2^nn^m$

Which means I get:

$An^m2^n-3A(n-1)^m2^{n-1}+2A(n-2)^m2^{n-2}=2^n$

I can easily reduce this to:

$An^m-3A(n-1)^m2^{-1}+A(n-2)^m2^{-1}=1$

But I'm not sure how to continue here. I'd be grateful if anyone could help me point me to the right direction. I'm not sure how to factor $n^m$.

EDIT:

The solution (thank you for helping!):

$a_n=\lambda_1+\lambda_2*2^n+2*n*2^n$

Comment: "point me to the right direction" How to choose $m$ so as to make $$C=2n^m-3(n-1)^m+(n-2)^n$$ constant? Then set $A=2/C$ and you are done.

Comment: That's it I assume, thank you!

Comment: Isn't setting $A=2/C$ unnecessary? If I can simply plug $m=0$ into the equation and just solve it that way.

Comment: No, $m=0$ leaves you with $$A-3A/2+A/2=1$$ which has no solution. So, I guess my first comment could read "How to choose $m$ so as to make $C=...$ constant and nonzero?"

Comment: Just realized it would be the same as not even taking $x=2$ into consideration. Turned out correct for $m=3$.

Comment: No, $m=3$ does not work.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to just keep plugging in different values until I find something or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: You are missing something really obvious. Which values of $m$ did you try?

Comment: $m=1$ seems to work. Not sure how I got the most obvious one wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Write down a solution to your own question? This is the way to really grasp the subject and is recommended on the site anyway, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate solution as a reference. Since the non-homogeneous is kind of special, we can proceed as follows.

**Solution**.  $\blacktriangleleft$ Divide the equation by $2^n$ we have
$$
\frac {a_n}{2^n} = \frac 32 \cdot \frac {a_{n-1}} {2^{n-1}} - \frac 12 \cdot \frac {a_{n-2}} {2^{n-2}} + 1. 
$$
Let $b_n = a_n \cdot 2^{-n}$, then replace $n$ by $n+1$ we have two equations:
\begin{alignat*}{5}
&b_{n+1} & - \frac 32 &b_n& + &\frac 12 b_{n-1}&  &&= &1&\\
&   & &b_n&   - & \frac 32 b_{n-1}& + &\frac 12 b_{n-2}& = &1&
\end{alignat*}
Subtract them we get a homogeneous recurrence
$$
b_{n+1} - \frac 52 b_n + 2 b_{n-1} - \frac 12 b_{n-2} = 0,
$$
whose characteristic polynomial is 
$$
2x^3 - 5x^2 + 4 x -1 = (x-1)(2x^2-3x + 1) = (x-1)^2 (2x-1),
$$
hence the general solution is 
$$
b_n = (c_1 + c_2 n) + c_3 2^{-n},
$$
and the solution to the original equation is 
$$
a_n = c_3 + (c_1 + c_2 n)\cdot 2^n. \blacktriangleright
$$

Now that I think about it, this seems like an indirect application to the Euler substitution. Maybe my post is redundant here...